# no able to get the value of textbox

Tags: javascript

```
<form id="myRegisterationForm">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="nameTextbox"  />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And the js is

```
var myform = document.getElementById('myRegisterationForm');
var name = document.getElementById('nameTextbox');


function onSubmit(e) {
    console.log(name.value);
    e.preventDefault();
}

myform.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit, false);
```

But somehow the value shows **undefined** for the text inside name textbox.... even when i enter something and press submit..why?

Comment: undefined is getting in the console.

Comment: Are the `var`s defined in the global scope? Browsers already define a global [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) for the `window` that can only store strings.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski well spotted

Comment: @Jonathan Yes thanks.. name is a reserved work for global. thanks.

Comment: Hey Jonathan put your answer and i will correct it

Answer (score 0):

```
var r = document.getElementById('nameTextbox').value;
//added .value
```

Use this to store the value of the text box in variable `r`.I have renamed the variable to `r`.

Answer (score 0):

The value property sets or returns the value of the value attribute of a text field.

```
document.getElementById("nameTextbox").value;
```

The getElementById method needs a pair of round brackets. In between these round brackets you type the ID you're trying to access. The ID needs to be surrounded by quote marks, single or double. Textboxes have a VALUE attribute. You can get at this value by adding it after the round brackets

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myform = document.getElementById('myRegisterationForm');



function onSubmit(e) {
  var name = document.getElementById('nameTextbox');
  alert(name.value);

  e.preventDefault();


}

myform.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit, false);
```

```html
<form id="myRegisterationForm">

  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="nameTextbox" />



  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```